# UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-9: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, encoding

When writing this code:

```
df['new'] = df.astype(str).apply(' '.join, axis=1)
```

it caused this:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-9: ordinal not in range(128)
```

The df contains Greek characters.

After reading about the encode in similar questions, I could't apply it to this situation and did it with:

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')
```

Although it worked. Everyone is not supporting the use of this. Since it may cause errors later I would like to see what you suggest in this specific case.

The data are imported with this: `DataFrame.from_records` https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_records.html so it can't accept encoding as a parameter.

Comment: Did you try setting the encoding to `ISO-8859-1` ?

Comment: at what point to set it

Comment: Try setting `encoding = "ISO-8859-1"` as a parameter in `pd.read_csv()`

Comment: the problem is that I read the data with this: `DataFrame.from_records` https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_records.html which doesn't have an encoding parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Try to simply encode string:

```
df['new'] = df.astype(str).apply(' '.join, axis=1).encode("utf-8")
```

and add this at the top of your code

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Comment: Looks promising. How to reset the setting I passed with `sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')` previously. So I can type your code?

Comment: @user51332 i never used sys setdefaultencoding, and have no problems. This method with # -*- coding: utf-8 -*- works for me everyday ;)

Comment: it is what you typed.I don't know why it is not working.The only thing that worked is what I  typed in the question. But it isn't the suggested way and prone to errors

Answer (score -2):

I found the reason is that our remote server cannot support Chinese. So, I have changed all the printed content into English.